# How to stop a running experiment in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

I am running an experiment in Google Analytics and I want to stop it. I am reading the documentation at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2366607?hl=en and it says:

> To stop a running experiment:
>
> 1. In the experiment list, click the name of the experiment that you want to stop.
> 2. In the menu bar, click STOP EXPERIMENT, then click the confirmation.

Where is the "menu bar" that they mention, which is where I am supposed to find this "STOP EXPERIMENT" link. Look at what I get when I go to my running experiment:

[image]

Edit:

It is right there. It says "Stop Experiment" in the navigation area on top with the gray background. I was expecting to find something more prominent like a button that is easy to see/find. This would probably be a usability feedback for Google, that they should make that button more prominent. I am used to running experiments in Optimizely and they have the play or pause button in a much more prominent way. I like the graphical user interface of Optimizely better than Google Analytics's GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It says "Stop Experiment" in the navigation bar with the gray background.